# Hat doesn't postition correctly when user avatar missing

Tags: bug, winter-bash

Just noticed this on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41250072/range-clearcontents-throwing-run-time-error-438#) (just as an example - the question isn't relevant).  The OP doesn't have an avatar picture (my guess is it's blocked on this PC), so the hat got tossed up and to the left:

[image: Hat miss]

If I click through to the user profile, the same thing happens there - just larger.

If it makes a difference, the browser is Firefox v50.0.2, OS is Linux Mint.

Comment: Cannot reproduce on chrome 55.0.2883.87 m or firefox 50.1.0 (Win7)- icons are blocked for me as well, but the hats are positioned correctly

Comment: can't reproduce the issue too , maybe it's just a minor glitch