# A user's hat is shown in topbar on the review page

Tags: bug, design, winter-bash-2016, firefox

I noticed that there is a hat shown in the left side of the topbar on the [review page](https://stackoverflow.com/review).

The hat links to [a user's profile page](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3361708/m-wi%c5%9bnicki). I suppose this user is a recent reviewer.

I am using Firefox 50.1.0. I couldn't reproduce this on other pages or on Chrome.

[image: Topbar with user profile link]

Comment: No repro with Firefox 50.1.0

Comment: Similar problem: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/340002/2675154